# I keep on getting the error that my .NET model needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am going through a .NET REST API tutorial which does CRUD for command line commands in .NET through a sql server backend. I am using postman to send requests to my endpoints, and if I send a post request to my endpoint it with just a object with all the req for the CommandCreateDTO, it comes up with this error:  `System.ArgumentException: Commander.Models.Command needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. (Parameter 'type')`. Thoughts?

**Controllers**

```
//POST api/commands
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<CommandCreateDto> CreateCommand(CommandCreateDto commandCreateDto)
        {
            var commandModel = _mapper.Map<Command>(commandCreateDto);
            _repository.CreateCommand(commandModel);
            _repository.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(commandModel);
    }
```

**CommandReadDto**

```
namespace Commander.Dtos
{
    public class CommandReadDto
    {
    
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string HowTo { get; set; }

        public string Line { get; set; }

        public CommandReadDto(int Id, string HowTo, string Line)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.HowTo = HowTo;
            this.Line = Line;
        }
        
    }
}
```

**CommandCreateDto**

```
namespace Commander.Dtos
{
    public class CommandCreateDto
    {
        public string HowTo { get; set; }

        public string Line { get; set; }

        public string Platform { get; set; }

        public CommandCreateDto(string HowTo, string Line, string Platform)
        {
            this.HowTo = HowTo;
            this.Line = Line;
            this.Platform = Platform;
        }
    }
}
```

**Command Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Commander.Models
{
    public class Command
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string HowTo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Line { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Platform { get; set; }

        public Command(int Id, string HowTo, string Line, string Platform)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.HowTo = HowTo;
            this.Line = Line;
            this.Platform = Platform;
        }
    }
}
```

**CommandsProfile**

```
using AutoMapper;
using Commander.Dtos;
using Commander.Models;

namespace Commander.Profiles
{
    public class CommandsProfile : Profile
    {
        public CommandsProfile()
        {
            //Source - Target
            CreateMap<Command, CommandReadDto>();
            CreateMap<CommandCreateDto, Command>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar that worked thanks for the help! I'm new to DTOs so now I'm just wondering how it did lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Automapper `CreateMap()` is trying to map Command class with `CommandReadDto`. To do that it is expecting default constructor(Constructor without any parameter) in your `Command` model.

To solve your problem add new default constructor to your `Command.Model` class.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Commander.Models
{
    public class Command
    {
        ...
        
        public Command(){}  //This is missing in your code.

        public Command(int Id, string HowTo, string Line, string Platform)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.HowTo = HowTo;
            this.Line = Line;
            this.Platform = Platform;
        }
    }
}
```